# Changing RDLC Report of ReportViewer - A data source instance has not been supplied for the data source error(WFA C#)

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, reportviewer

I'm trying to change the RDLC report loaded onto a reportviewer on a form. I have the report source set to *rptStaff* whenever it loads as seen below.
[Form when loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH68u.png) . However, I want the report to change in the reportviewer from *rptStaff* to the *LoginDetails* report when the button in clicked. I have used this code to try to achieve this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //rptv.Reset();

        ReportDataSource RDS = new ReportDataSource();
        RDS.Name = "LoginDetails";
        RDS.Value = this.LoginDetailsBindingSource;
        this.rptv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(RDS);
        this.rptv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "LoginDetails.rdlc";
        this.rptv.RefreshReport();
    }
```

When I click button1 on the report, an error shows in the reportviewer [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3Wo.png).
I want the report *LoginDetails* to show on the reportviewer once the button has been clicked.

Here is the code for the reportviewer, however I don't know if it is useful or not:

```
        // 
        // rptv
        // 
        reportDataSource1.Name = "dsAllStaffDetails";
        reportDataSource1.Value = this.StaffBindingSource;
        this.rptv.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
        this.rptv.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "WoodsideCommunityHub.rptStaff.rdlc";
        this.rptv.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(11, 69);
        this.rptv.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(2);
        this.rptv.Name = "rptv";
        this.rptv.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(951, 359);
        this.rptv.TabIndex = 0;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I fixed the problem above by specifying the exact Report path with `this.rptv.LocalReport.ReportPath("exact path here");`

I am now getting the following error: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPIdH.png)

Please note, I have no DataSource / DataSet in my project entitled DataSet1

Comment: What database are you using?  Where is the WoodsideCommunityHub.rptStaff.rdlc file located?

Comment: Apologies, I am using an SQL Server database entitled WoodsideCommunityHub. Also, the rptStaff.rdlc file is located in the main directory of the program where all the forms etc are stored.

Comment: Did you add the report to the project? See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/75a46847-806e-49da-96b5-691e31813f6e/how-to-a-add-rdlc-file-to-a-projectsolution-in-visual-studio?forum=sqlreportingservices

Comment: @jdweng yeah they were added to the project, fixed that problem, however have a new error showing in the reportviewer shown in the edit above. Thanks.

Comment: Where is Dataset 1? Open the rdlc with notepad and see if you can find DataSet1.  The rdlc has a tag ContentText with your query.  The query is probably failing.  You can extract the query and test by placing into SQL Server Management Studio query.  The file is html so you may have to replace the special html character with there string version like &amp; with just the ampersand character.

Comment: @jdweng In the rdlc file, I have two locations which have DataSet 1, one [here](http://prntscr.com/mxgxc1) and another [here](http://prntscr.com/mxgxos). Also, there is no tag called ContentText in the rdlc file.

Comment: @jdweng got it fixed! changed where it said DataSet1 to dsLoginDetails and that solved it. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: I meant CommandText. The second link has CommandText with no SQL Statement  the query is just a comment.  It looks like you created a dummy query.